# Configuring an Application Load Balancer for Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure an ALB for my elb deployment. 
I've followed the aws [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html)

but when I'm running `eb create test-env --elb-type application`

I get: `eb: error: unrecognized arguments: --elb-type application`

I've updated my eb cli using aws [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html)
(running EB CLI 3.7.6 (Python 2.7.1))

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an older version of the EB CLI. The support for Application Load Balancers was added in 3.7.8: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli

You can upgrade your CLI version by running:

`pip install --upgrade awsebcli`